# How do you "Run" a class

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

I'm still a newbie when it comes to Dynamics AX development.

I'm working through a tutorial here. Once finished writing the code in C# and X++ the tutorial says to run the class and messages will be displayed (the result of the test code).

I can find no explanation of how to "run" a method or class within the AX development workspace. I found "Go (F5)", but nothing happens (and I have breaks in both codes right at the beginning, so it couldn't be a silent error (if there is such a thing).

Any help you can give would be appreciated.

Kevin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have several options.

1. Create a X++ job in the Jobs AOT node. Place code that invokes your
   class in the job body and press F5 to run.
2. Create a main method on your class with the following signature:

   ```
   static void main (Args _args) 
   { 
       // Your X++ code here. 
   }
   ```

   You can execute this method by pressing F5 when the class is open in
   the code editor. Be aware that this method gets invoked when a class
   is associated with a menu item, so not all production classes will
   need this method. Works great for testing though. See this for more
   detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa673265.aspx

Comment: You should generally point a menu item at your class to run the main method(although jobs can be useful for testing, invoking code from a job may cause the code to be run client side--and there are subtle differences in the way some code behaves client vs server)

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to manually run the class you could also execute your class via the browser. For example in my sandbox environment:

https://yourUrl.sandbox.dynamics.com/?cmp=DAT&mi=SysClassRunner&cls=ClassNameHere

This would execute the class "ClassNameHere" manually.